# Programmatically written cells of UITableView are in the same place

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

Interface:

[image]

Interface in debugger:

[image]

Here is configuration of tableview

```
private func configureTableView(){
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    // tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.register(DishCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "dishCell")
    
    // tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

}
```

Here is tableView extensions

```
extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 380
        }
        return 48
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 122
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}

extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return viewModel.dishes.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.dishes[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let dishType = viewModel.dishTypes[section]
        
        if section == 0 {
            let restaurant = viewModel.restaurant
            return FirstMenuHeader(restaurant: restaurant, dishType: dishType)
        }else{
            return DefaultMenuHeader(dishType: dishType)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dishCell") as! DishCell
        
        let dish = viewModel.dishes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.set(dish: dish)
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Just to clarify DishCell, FirstMenuHeader and DefaultMenuHeader look well if you put them outside of UITableview. And they have constraints that define their height. However their height is dynamic and depends on amount of line of text.

Comment: Can you show the `DishCell`?  Also, your dequeue in `cellForRow` doesn't look correct. The code you have should crash since you aren't passing an index path, i oud expect the dequeue to return `nil` initially since there are no cells in the reuse pool.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in dishCell.I made constraints with view, while I had to make constraints with contentView.
I have rewrote my constraints and problem was resolved.